# Angular JS: using an If statement to take an action

Tags: angularjs

Angular newbie. How do I make an alert box appear when count=3?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="count=0">
  <h1>Count: {{ count }}</h1>
<a ng-click="countsUp(count)">Click here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried using an If statement but when I click the link, this makes count=3 straight away without counting up in steps.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.countsUp=function(){
$scope.count=$scope.count+1;
if ($scope.count=3){alert('count is 3')};
};
}]);
```

See:
http://codepen.io/angeltapes/pen/qdwerw/

Thanks, any help welcome. I've looked into $watch to do this but it seems be be used for updating the DOM rather than executing functions.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:
`if ($scope.count=3)`

With:
`if ($scope.count == 3)`

***Suggestion:*** *Add some indentation to make your code more readable. Example:*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.countsUp = function() {
        $scope.count = $scope.count+1;

        if ($scope.count == 3) {
            alert('count is 3');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
if($scope.count=3)
```

to

```
if($scope.count==3)
```